# TTL Index definition with Spring Data

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, ttl

I want to create TTL index with Spring Data Annotations. In my case, I can't use `@Indexed(name = "ttl_index", expireAfterSeconds: 1000)` put on the field of the class, but I want to define the index at the class level with `CompoundIndex`.
It is possible ? I hope so. Alternatively, can I use indexes with `Java` without using annotations?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. Only with `@Indexed` Spring Data MongoDB api.

As [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/index.html) says, one of the restrictions is:
TTL indexes are a single-field indexes. Compound indexes do not support TTL and ignore the `expireAfterSeconds` option.